# npm install Puppeteer@8.0.0 fails on raspbian

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, puppeteer, raspbian

On raspbian running :

```
npm install Puppeteer@8.0.0
```

should result in

```
succesfull installation
```

but we run into :

```
...
verbose stack Error: command failed
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/jsoto/.nvm/versions/node/v15.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5
...
npm ERR! code 143 
npm ERR! path /home/jsoto/test/node_modules/puppeteer  
npm ERR! command failed  
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js  
npm ERR! Terminated`
```

My environnement is the following:
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Processor| ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)|
| Product  | Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4|
| Software | Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)|
| Puppeteer version| 8.0.0|
| Node.js version| v15.11.0|
| npm version| 7.6.2|

Comment: Can you download other packages?

Comment: Check your dmesg. Are you getting an out-of-memory error?

Comment: Seems to be okay now ! Thanks